# how to assign same event to different objects?

Tags: c#, events

Im usying a component that have an OnData event. I want to create 100 object from this component with almost same OnData  event.

my code is like this:

```
        Tcp[] arrTcp = new Tcp[100];

        for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            arrTcp[i] = new Tcp();

            arrTcp[i].Data += tcp1_Data;
        }
```

but OnData event is a bit diffrent in each tcp object.

```
    void tcp1_Data(object sender, Dart.Sockets.DataEventArgs e)
    {

        // all code are same except this part :

        if(tcp1)
            Console.WriteLine("tcp1");

        if(tcp2)
            Console.WriteLine("tcp2");

        .....
    }
```

I dont want to write 100 events... any idea?

for more information: tcp1_Data will fire by multi threading ...

Comment: Is that part that is different is as simple as you have in your example?  Or is there some complex logic to deal with?

Comment: no its sample. in fact its complex logic... @malkassem

Comment: What do you want to happen inside `tcp1_Data()`? It's not clear.

Comment: its sample @HenkHolterman. the logic is a bit complex. I want to know is there any way to have 1 event for 100 object but not exactly same behavior?

Comment: You already have that. For a better answer we need more details about _not exactly same behavior_.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I add some information in my question

Comment: Then the answer is: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: so? how its possible @HenkHolterman ?

Comment: A suitable depends on "how different" the differences are. If an additional parameter would do (as it looks like in your example), you could capture the variable in a lambda expression which you attach to the event handler. If there's a whole different action to be taken, your question is logically flawed: You want to attach the *same* event handler, but it should do *different* things. Whether and how this case can be solved elegantly depends on the details. Your vague description of "complex logic" doesn't even make it clear if generalizing it with merely a `for` loop is even appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
var arrTcp = new Tcp[100];

var specificCode = new Dictionary<int, Action<int, Tcp>>()
{
    { 0, (index, tcp) => Console.WriteLine("tcp1") },
    { 1, (index, tcp) => Console.WriteLine("tcp2") },
    // ...
    { 99, (index, tcp) => Console.WriteLine("tcp100") },
};

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    arrTcp[i] = new Tcp();

    var index = i;
    arrTcp[i].Data += (s, e) =>
    {
        // all code are same except for :
        specificCode[index](index, arrTcp[index]);
    };
}
```

Now, this isn't a great improvement except that it probably makes the code slightly more maintainable. However, depending on the complexity in the code in the `specificCode` dictionary, this might even be worse to maintain.

I suspect that the problem you are trying to solve here isn't actually about writing custom code for each event handler. I think you probably have an underlying issue that you thought could be solved in this way. If you could post another question with your underlying need I think we could help you more.